# Rails unedited form fields if db column is NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, form-for

Let me try to present a simple example here:

I have db table `Orders` and a column `delivery_address`.

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>    
  <%= f.text_field :delivery_address %> 
<% end %>
```

If no change is made on the form, when the form is submitted the value of `Orders.delivery_address` changes from `NULL` to empty value.

and I set a alert notice which looks like:

`test@gmail.com changed delivery_address to .`

Any suggestion how to prevent updating db fields with NULL values to empty by default with rails update action.

Comment: Perhaps a different approach is needed and you should ensure a delivery address is ALWAYS supplied by adding a presence of validation?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in the model:

```
# In the Order model
before_validation do
  self.delivery_address = nil if delivery_address.blank?
end
```

I also really don't like that this happens, but the other alternative is to do it on the controller level